# image will display in dreamweaver but shows a blank in web browser

Tags: dreamweaver

The image index_03.jpg will display in Dreamweaver but does not show in the browser. All of the files are in the appropriate place I have checked, could it be something with my code?

```
      <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="wrapper2">
        <div id="header">
          <div id="logo">
            <h1><img src="images/index_03.jpg" alt="" width="508" height="130" /></a></h1>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you upload that directory and image to your server?  If it's not there, it will be broken because the web server can't find it.  Where do you have this page?  Do you have a link you can share w/us?

Comment: At the moment it is not uploaded anywhere im just doing everything localy.is there a place where I could test it or try?

Comment: If you're running it locally, do you have your images directory in the same directory as your index.html file (or whatever file this is that you're editing and not seeing the images in)?  It is looking from the current directory to the images directory (in the same folder) and then for the specific image.

Comment: Yes, it is in the same folder, I have checked several times to be sure.

Comment: as a side note, other images are showing, but they are a in a gif format. The other is jpg

Comment: I would suggest putting it live somewhere so that I can look and help figure it out.  It could be as simple as a naming issue though... Make sure everything is spelled exactly right, which I'm sure you've already done.